# How to use Electron-Forge Typescript + webpack plugin with Electron-Builder

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder, electron-forge

**What I did** - I'm using `electron forge typescript & webpack` template . Also I want to use `electron-builder` instead of `Electron-Forge` windows maker windows.squirell because of the nsis packaging option.

**The Error** - The application runs in development mode correctly. However, in the packaged application I get a white screen.

I **suspect** that the builder is not using the build files generated by `"@electron-forge/plugin-webpack"`

[image]

**Electron-Builder Config**

```
  "build": {
    "appId": "cloudapp",
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ],
      "icon": "./src/images/cloudappLogo Icon.ico",
      "requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "installerIcon": "./src/images/cloudappIcon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "./src/images/cloudappLogo Icon.ico",
      "uninstallDisplayName": "cloudapp",
      "license": "license.txt",
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
    }
  },
```

**Electron-Forge Config**

```
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "plugins": [
        [
          "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          {
            "mainConfig": "./webpack/webpack.main.config.js",
            "renderer": {
              "config": "./webpack/webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "html": "./public/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/index.tsx",
                  "name": "main_window",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./electron/bridge.ts"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using the following steps:

1. Install https://github.com/imxeno/electron-forge-maker-nsis

> npm i @imxeno/electron-forge-maker-nsis

forge.config.ts, add to makers array:

```
{
  name: '@imxeno/electron-forge-maker-nsis',
  config: {}
},
```

Create electron-builder.js:

```
exports.default = function () {
  return {
    "productName": "...",
    "appId": "...",
    "nsis": {
        "oneClick": false,
        "runAfterFinish": true,
        ...
  }
};
```

}

Run `npm run publish`

Answer (score 0):

I had to package my files using Electron Forge and built an installer using electron-builder after I packaged app.

Comment: Would you happen to have open sourced that installer?

Comment: That's on my to-do list :)

Comment: @Ibra I am also very interested in how you did this!